# Replace all elements name and attrbiutes that contains hyphens with underscore

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML example:

```
<root-name file="something" date="22.02.2015" target="name" full-name="something else">
   <root-child title ="title" published-by="FullName" published-by-userid="username">
       <root-doc id="123" owner-id="username" />
       <root-doc id="1234" owner-id="username" />
       <root-doc id="12345" owner-id="username" />
   </root-child>

   <root-child title ="title" published-by="FullName" published-by-userid="username">
       <root-doc id="abc" owner-id="username" />
       <root-doc id="abcd" owner-id="username" />
       <root-doc id="abcde" owner-id="username" />
   </root-child>
..................    
</root-name>
```

How can I replace all elements names and attributes that contain hyphen to underscore?

Example:

```
<root-name file="something" date="22.02.2015" target="name" full-name="something else">
```

should be

```
<root_name file="something" date="22.02.2015" target="name" full_name="something else">
```

Comment: Why? You don't need it to parse your xml.

Comment: I actually parse this xml to dynamic object and the properties doesn't work when the name contains hyphen so I was thinking to first replace all hyphens with underscore and then parse it to dynamic object.

Comment: `I actually parse this xml to dynamic object` Can you post the code?

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/tucaz/XmlToObjectParser/blob/master/trunk/src/XmlToObjectParser/XmlToObjectParser.cs

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attributes names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are a little trickier than element names because attribute names do not have a setter.  Thus:

```
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
        {
            if (element.Name.LocalName.Contains("-"))
            {
                var newName = element.Name.LocalName.Replace('-', '_');
                element.Name = element.Name.Namespace + newName;
            }
            var list = element.Attributes().ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var attr = list[i];
                if (attr.Name.LocalName.Contains("-"))
                {
                    XAttribute newAttr = new XAttribute(attr.Name.Namespace + attr.Name.LocalName.Replace('-', '_'), attr.Value);
                    list[i] = newAttr;
                }
            }
            element.ReplaceAttributes(list);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("F:\\save.xml"));
        xdoc.Descendants().All(m => { Replace(m); return true; });

        Console.Write(xdoc.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Replace(XElement node)
    {
        if (node.Name.LocalName.IndexOf("-") > -1)
        {
            node.Name = node.Name.LocalName.Replace('-', '_');
        }

        node.Attributes().All(m => { Replace(m); return true;});
    }

    static void Replace(XAttribute node)
    {
        if (node.Name.LocalName.IndexOf("-") > -1)
        {
            XAttribute xa = new XAttribute(node.Name.LocalName.Replace('-', '_'), node.Value);
            node.Parent.Add(xa);
            node.Remove();
        }
    }
```